# javascript and css not working in safari and ie

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, safari

I'm working on [this site](http://www.diegoguizar.com/cristinafrancov/galeria.html), which works good in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari or IE.

The round images should change to full size (650px width) image when clicked in a 0.6s transition.

In Safari the border radius in the images is ignored (they are square divs), and the transition doesn't work well, images overlap during transition time..

In Internet Explorer the javascript doesn't do anything, javascript is working, you can see in the paragraph above the images, changing the language works (that's js).

I'm green in all this, so I would like to know what's wrong with this.. how can I fix it?

As far as I know this is not hard for browser to do, and I know the fame IE has, but still this is simple javascript, it has to work doesn't it?

This is how the html of each image looks:

```
    <a name="t1"></a>
    <a href="#t1">
    <div class="galeria">
        <div class="normal" id="t1" onclick="SelectOrUnSelect(t1)">
            <img src="galeria/obra/1.Naturaleza.jpg" />
            <p>Relato I. Naturaleza</p>
            <p>Tale I. Nature</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>
```

Here's the javascript that changes the class of the images:

```
var divSelected = null;
function SelectOrUnSelect(x)
{
if(divSelected != null) divSelected.className = 'normal';
divSelected = x;
x.className = 'activa';
}
```

and the css:

```
.normal{
width:200px;
min-height:0;
max-height:0;
padding:100px 0;
margin:20px auto;
overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius:100px;
    -moz-border-radius:100px;
    -o-border-radius:100px;
border-radius:100px;
    -webkit-transition:0.6s;
    -moz-transition:0.6s;
    -o-transition:0.6s;
transition:0.6s;
}


.normal img{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:-100px 0;
    width:150%;
    position: relative;
    left: -30%;
    top:0;
}



.activa{ 
width:100%;
min-height:400px;
border-radius:0;
padding:0;
margin:0 auto;
-webkit-transition:0.6s;
-moz-transition:0.6s;
-o-transition:0.6s;
transition:0.6s;
display:block;
}

.activa:last-child{ 
    margin:0 auto 55px auto;
}

.activa img{
    width:100%;
        -webkit-border-radius:0.2%;
        -moz-border-radius:0.2%;
        -o-border-radius:0.2%;
    border-radius:0.2%;
}
```

Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: Please add relevant code to the question. Also, the link appears to be broken.

Comment: done, thanks.. i'm new in all this sorry..

Comment: Any idea on why this doesn't work?

Comment: Well, for example: On old Safari it doesn't work setting `border-radius` in percentage.

Comment: Oh BTW, which version of IE did you test the site on?

Comment: ie11, changed the radius to pixels but safari still displays squares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few things to try.

Fix the doctype, it should be: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Use `getElementById`:

```
function SelectOrUnSelect(x) {
    if (divSelected != null) {
        divSelected.className = 'normal';
    }
    var el = document.getElementById(x);
    divSelected = el;
    el.className = 'activa';
}
```

and change the inline code param to a string, e.g.:

```
SelectOrUnSelect('t1')
```

Comment: I fixed the doctype, the function worked the same way (and still did nothing in ie, s thanks for reading and helping with an answer

Comment: Strange, this worked on IE when I tried it. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors in the console. sorry for the late answer, i've been out of town

Comment: I must have done something wrong the first time cuz i tried it again and internet explorer works now! thank you very much!!